# Mac support for Blu-Ray

Tags: usb, hardware-recommendation, blu-ray

I would like to buy an external Blu-Ray drive. I have a specific model in mind (the LG CP40NG10), but I'm open to suggestions if anybody has a different one they recommend.

The documentation says that it has "Mac support: Yes (DVD)", but does this imply that it has Blu-Ray support on Macs? There is a [new Mac Blu-Ray player](http://www.macblurayplayer.com/) software package and tips to read video Blu-Ray discs with [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/) + VLC.

Does anybody know if it's possible to read Blu-Ray discs under OS X with this LG drive or where I can find a list of hardware supporting these two software products?

I have a MacBook Pro Core 2 Duo 2.53 GHz on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: it sounds like what you're trying to ask is, "Will the combination of <THIS DRIVE> and <THIS SOFTWARE> allow me to play blu-ray disks on my mac?  If not, is there a combination that will?"  It eliminates the sense of many questions, and the feel that it's looking for a list of shopping recs (which I know you're not).  Try revising to get re-opened.

Comment: I found this : « Storeva Slim Burner » on french mac hardware store, but don't want this brand…

Answer (score 1):

For this specific model according to "Allthingstech" (in a comment on web store):

> Allthingstech from Corona, California on 06/19/2012
>   Purchased this for my new Macbook Pro with Retina Display. The MB can recognize the drive regardless what the Lg packaging says. Had to use third party software ( Mac Blu-Ray Player) for playback. (…) So far the drive has worked perfectly with stellar Bluray playback and absolutely no stuttering or lag.(…)

[source](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/LG---8x-External-USB-2.0-3D-Blu-ray-Disc-Double-Layer-DVD±RW/CD-RW-Drive/3794001.p?id=1218432163829&skuId=3794001)

And OS X since Leopard can read Blu-Ray-Rom with any drive, the problem is to read protected video (all commercial Blu-Ray).

Comment: Can you post a link to the comment, or at least to the page where you found it?

Comment: Thank you @CajunLuke, do you think "Allthingstech" could be a fake user (but why doing this)?

Comment: Probably not, it's just good practice to link to sources of material around here.

Comment: I finally bought this combo model : Asus - SBC-06D2X-U and I can read Blu-Ray on my MacBook ! (This drive does NOT write blu ray discs)

Comment: I'm using LG BP40NS20 and it works fine with MakeMKV.